# android material design with AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

To support API 19 and below I let my activities extend AppCompatActivity.
I tried to set the following parent theme for v21 `parent="android:Theme.Material"`
When I tried to ran my app it gave an exception and told me to use Activity instead of AppCompatActivity.

Does this mean I have to create new Activities which extend Activity for API 21 and above in order to get material design? Or is there a better way?

Comment: To get material design, you need to extend Theme.AppCompat

Comment: Yeah I did, read it again

Comment: You don't want to extend Theme.Material directly as such;

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. it's actually a good question. @Eenvincible might be right, but Google's tutorial uses Theme.Material. See http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html.

Comment: You can use Material directly BUT must have a folder called values-v21

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `AppCompatActivity` requires an **AppCompat theme**.
Using a different theme, like the `android:Theme.Material` you will get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

Just define a Theme in your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

With the AppCompat theme you can have the Material design also in device with API <21.

The `android:Theme.Material` can be use only with API >= 21.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have setup my themes.xml file to support material design:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Now, in your activity, you can extend AppCompatActivity as usual and you will get the looks you want! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I myself was confused by this when reading Google's tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html. Not sure if maybe there is a better Google tutorial out there that actually mentions backwards support.